# Does Grails 2.3.x Support JDK 8

Tags: grails, java-8

It seems like this questions should be easy but the installation requirements for Grails (http://www.grails.org/Installation) haven't been updated in 2 years.  Does anyone know for sure is Grails 2.3 will run on JDK 8?

Comment: Good question. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: No, I haven't but I'm assuming that it will probably work if I try it; what I'm wondering is if Java 8 is supported not if it work.  I'm wondering if the VMWare and the Grails community is actively using and testing Grails on Java 8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As noticed by [heikkim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92063/heikkim) this ticket which is now closed suggests that support for Java 8 will start on Grails 2.4:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11063 (title: Java 8 support)

Comment: UPDATE: The ticket is closed (on 15th of May) but Java8 support is apparently for Grails 2.4 only.

Answer (score 4):

Tried an app (built on v2.3.7) on JDK 8 and hit a road block with database-migration plugin while compiling the app. If that particular plugin is commented out then everything looks good during compilation.

Running the app (with a sample controller) throws an error related to `withFormat` method from `grails-plugin-mimetypes`. Looking into it.

Raised an [improvement defect](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-171) for grails-database-migration plugin. I think this may not be required as well but making grails JDK8 compatible might need changes in `grails-core`. However, I have not checked with latest milestone build for Grails 2.4 which might already be taking care of those compatibility issues.