# Grails 2.3.7 error when creating a new project

Tags: grails-2.3

I just a fresh install: I downloaded and installed JDK and GGTS. I then created a new Grails 2.3.7 project and I get the error message below. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

> Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for partial output)
>   Command: GrailsCommand(P/MangaReader> compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies)
>   ---- System.out ----
>   Loading Grails 2.3.7
>   .
>   |Environment set to development
>   ..........
>   |Compiling 79 source files
>   .Error 
>   |
>   Compilation error: startup failed:
>   C:\Users\\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MangaReader\target\work\plugins\database-migration-1.3.8\grails-app\controllers\grails\plugin\databasemigration\DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
>    @ line -1, column -1.
>   C:\Users\\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MangaReader\target\work\plugins\database-migration-1.3.8\grails-app\controllers\grails\plugin\databasemigration\DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
>    @ line -1, column -1.
>   2 errors
>   Error |
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:733)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
>   Error |
>       at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:773)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:571)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:421)
>   Error |
>       at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
>   Error |
>       at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
>   Error |
>       at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
>   Error |
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.exit(BaseSettingsApi.java:382)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:953)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1132)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1088)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>   Error |
>       at _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:77)
>   Error |
>       at _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>   Error |
>       at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:60)
>   Error |
>       at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:354)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:953)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1132)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1088)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
>   Error |
>       at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:57)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>   Error |
>       at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:44)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error |
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
>   Error |
>       at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
>   Error |
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)

Comment: I got it, too. I'm investigating whether or not this has to do with Java 8. I just installed Java 8 and I'm wondering if that version is too new.

Answer (score 15):

I found this thread: 
[Does Grails 2.3.x Support JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517916/does-grails-2-3-x-support-jdk-8)

I backed my JDK from version 8 to version 7 (1.7.0_45). That fixed the issue.

Basically grails 2.3.7 (and below) does not support JDK 8 yet.

Comment: If you are using Windows remember that you must change JDK path on both PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's the GGTS, if you just use the command line Grails 2.3.7 works just fine on JDK 8 (also, make sure you have the latest JDK 8).

Answer (score 0):

It's de jdk version and the eclipse.ini file, you will need to install JDK 1.7 or lessen the version.

Change it in

`Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs`

In eclipse.ini add the next two lines

`-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin`

Answer (score 0):

grails 2.5.0 and jdk8 does not work either.
tried thru cmd and ggts