# Add New Controller Into Existing Grails Project

Tags: grails

I have an existing Grails project. Success run on my computer. And then I add new Controller into this one. I get an error like this:

```
Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object
withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)'
```

Comment: Paste the relevant code here

Comment: I just right-click in project > New > Grails Controller. In my class just class name (empty class)

Comment: Try deleting every thing from target directory of your project. Also delete your project directory from .<user-home>/.grails/<grails-verion>/projects/<project-name> directory and run the application again

Comment: This might helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229245/grails-2-3-7-new-project-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get sollution for my problem by downgrade my JDK from 8 to 7. I do these steps:

1. Download JDK 7 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
2. Setup environment variable of JAVA_HOME to JDK 7 (export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79)
3. Run these commands to clean and run

> grails clean
>   grails run-app

Comment: I don't believe you have to downgrade to JDK 7. But running "grails clean" should help.