# Grails classpath issue

Tags: grails, classpath

I have a problem when trying to compile a project using "grails compile". I get the following error:

```
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script Compile: startup failed:
_GrailsClasspath_groovy: 17: unable to resolve class 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler
@ line 17, column 1.
```

I am very new with groovy/grails, but I assume this is a problem with some classpath somewhere. However, I can't find any file containing the string "GrailsProjectCompiler" in my project. I tried searching google and stackoverflow for similar problems, but the only one I found (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-resolve-class-org-codehaus-groovy-grails-compiler-GrailsProjectCompiler-td4641043.html) did not work for me.

Does any one have any suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Edit: Grails is version 2.3, this is Mac OS X El Capitan running JDK 1.8

Comment: Which Grails version, which OS, which JAVA?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Added the versions you requested to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in question: [Does Grails 2.3.x Support JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517916/does-grails-2-3-x-support-jdk-8)

> Support for Java 8 had been added since Grails 2.4.

Try JAVA 1.7

Comment: While this is good advice, I do not believe this will fix my problem, as the project was running a while ago (with java 1.8). This problem first occurred when I moved dependencies from codehaus to maven central (I know codehaus is taken down, this is a legacy project at my firm, and hadn't been updated for a long while).
Will try tomorrow though!

Comment: No dice. Java 1.7 did not help.

Comment: Did you try classic `grails clean` and `grails compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies` before `grails run-app`?

Comment: I tried that. But I get this error:
 "_GrailsClean_groovy: 33: unable to resolve class GrailsProjectCleaner"

Comment: Which ide are you using? Does error occur if you run project from console? Did you try to re-import project?

Comment: There were a lot of issues with the project. In the end it turned out to be incompatible with the combination of java and grails versions specified in the project documentation, and a bunch of dependency issues because of this. Thanks for your help though! Your answer pointed me in the right direction.