# Grails 2.3.9 OutOfMemoryException

Tags: tomcat, grails

Note: This is my very first foray into Grails.

This occurred during a functional test within Tomcat, I'm assuming, since that is what the configuration shows:

```
...
build ":tomcat:7.0.70"
...
```

It's an old test app that I'm updating to Java 8. We don't have much interest in making it super-duper though as it is not production code. Where do I adjust the tomcat settings?

Comment: Well I thought I had found it for a moment there but I guess not. I found this: https://grails.org/plugin/tomcat ...but I set everything to 1g (this machine has plenty of memory) and then got a similar error on startup. Seems like a Russian Doll problem. A JVM memory spec inside another. There's Java, Groovy ( Grails also? It has it's own startup script) and Tomcat and I've got to figure which has the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517916/does-grails-2-3-x-support-jdk-8  You need to move over to grails 2.4+ for jdk8.  Unless you are learning something I suggest going even later into 3

Comment: Well are you saying there's a known issue? So far I've not had as much success with later versions than with this one.  Also I've not much of a mandate to work on this so we are taking the short path where ever possible.

Comment: https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/  Basically the version of groovy that was running pre 2.4 did not support JDK 8 properly and had some issues. When grails 2.4.0 moved over to later version of groovy that then fixed the problem and you could then use JDK8 with a grails app. You have raised a problem about 2.3.9 this is your answer. If you have problems with 2.4.+ then probably look at a new issue that calrifies exact issue

Comment: OIC, I did not know there was a KNOWN issue. That is different by far, to me, than just suspected.

Comment: I've upgraded to Grails 2.4.5 Same issue. I'm going to try editing the start scripts for grails and groovy.

Comment: tests should really be compared to a brand new app under 2.4.5 and jdk8 compared to your upgrade and jdk8.. It does support it from 2.4.0+ so unsure of the specific's of your circumstance -

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.3 enabled the forked execution mode by default (ie starting a second JVM to execute the tests (as you mention in your comment)).

The guide has more information about how to change the JVM settings for the child JVM (in short, they're in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy)

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.9/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode - thanks @brad-rippe for the updated link.

Comment: OK but I've tried setting them here and the situation doesn't seem to change much.

Comment: Documentation can be found at https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.9/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode