# Missing Dependency java/sql/Date while using Grails in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I am trying to import a Grails Project into the Eclipse IDE.  When I try to edit the file `BuildConfig.groovy` within my project, I keep getting an error popup that says the following:

`Unable to load class org.codehaus.runtime.DateGroovyMethods due to missing dependency java/sql/Date`

I have the following settings in place inside Eclipse Mars 2:

1. **Java JDK 1.7**
2. **Grails 2.2.4**

I tried right-clicking on my project and selected **Grails Tools** > **Refresh Dependencies** but that still hasn't solved the issue.

I am new to using Eclipse and Grails, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be using JDK 8; version 7 is passed its support life.

Comment: @duffymo So originally I tried using JDK 8 but when I use that for this particular project in Eclipse, I get the following error `Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke methods getAt() on null object`  This occurs when I try using the `Refresh Dependencies` command on my project.  The other reason I'm using JDK 7 is because that is the original Java SDK that was used for this project.

Comment: I don't know what that message means.  I'm not a Gradle user.  Works fine with Maven.

Comment: Can you try the grails clean command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517916/does-grails-2-3-x-support-jdk-8 grails 2.4+ for jdk8 and yes security flaws in 7 - why use eclipse if you are running 2.2.4 find sts or ggts which comes packed with grails u may then need to change the grails version internally to suite your needs